# Echo or print a value from sql table using PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, echo

[image]

I am trying to echo or print the last value of column **usercode** using PHP PDO. I tried to do this by using **name** column and SESSION var which will be the last values as references, but it doesn't work.

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'];

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT usercode from users where name = $name ");
$query->execute();

$result = $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

echo $result;
```

Comment: `setFetchMode` sets a mode. It does not fetch any result.

Comment: There are examples in the PDO manual. Try doing proper research before posting question.

Comment: I even give you a link http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php#refsect1-pdostatement.setfetchmode-returnvalues

Comment: You should be getting an error from that query, since you didn't put quotes around `$name`. But you should use bound parameters, then that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'];

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT usercode from users where name=:name");
$query = $db->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->execute();

$row = $query->fetch();

echo $row['usercode'];
```

`bindParam` is used when you just want to bind a variable reference to a parameter in the query.

Comment: Dont need to use named paramaters. You can also use question marks which is similar to `mysqli`

Comment: @SuperDJ I don't really see a difference between the two... really it depends if you're using PDO with MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements... I've always gone with the second one.

Comment: @SuperDJ You don't have to, but why wouldn't you? It makes queries and `bindParam()` calls so much easier to read.

Comment: just thoughts: I think it is a bit long when there is only one parameter. also, I am not a fan of bound parameters. I would: `$db->prepare("SELECT usercode from users where name = ?);` and: `$query->execute([$name]);` in this case.

Comment: @TheCodesee, JFYI: [fetchColumn()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn)

Comment: @Ryan Vincent Thank you and i mean it.